# Open new html page inside phonegap app

Tags: html, cordova

The thing with phonegap is that it uses it's own API via phonegap.js that is declared at the head of the index.html page.
When using window.open and it's alternatives, the new page will forget anything from the previous one, and phonegap's API would no longer be accessible.
What is the right way to open a new html file?
I really find it hard to believe that phonegap apps have to be one huge html file.

Answer (score 1):

Does your phonegap app need to open a new page? The idea of phonegap is 1-page app. Meaning that to change the view, you don't need to reload the whole DOM tree. Rather you load your DOM only once and then manipulate objects inside it.

Comment: I see, but then if my app have a lot of info in it, it will make the index.html file huge, is this the only way to work with it ?

Comment: If you are using a framework like Angularjs, you have access to a few very solid routing solutions.  To name a few, there is the built in router, the new router in 1.4 and also the ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router has an easy example.)  Outside of Angular, there is a ton of routing frameworks that will help you split up your application in to managble views.  Try a search for javascript routing, and see which you like.

Comment: Look into Ionic framework. It's beautiful, fast and built on AngularJS. And it's perfect for Phonegap. Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gApduktFwxw. And this tutorial: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/ionic-angularjs-and-phonegap-build/

Answer (score 0):

You can move to another html page by this code:

```
window.location = "NewFile.html";
```

Comment: Thanks, but will it preserve the dependencies ( scripts, css, etc... )? because i'm pretty sure it won't.

Comment: No it won't. You can then use panels in one html page and set there display none and block property as per you requirment. It will feel like the page is changing.

Comment: Sounds cool! i already did something else but i will keep that in mind. thank you very much! :)

Comment: Can you please share with us what alternative you used to make things work?

Comment: Sure, i just added all the dependencies include phonegap to each page, like so:

    <script src="../../phonegap.js></script>

and i checked if the cordova object exists and it does so i hope it will get the work done.